# Examples of downloading files from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-blob-storage, node-request

I am able to upload files to Azure blob storage via Node/Express without issue, but have found very minimal documentation/full examples of how to download a file. I found this on the tutorial page, but did not have any luck:

```
blobSvc.getBlobToStream('mycontainer', 'myblob', fs.createWriteStream('output.txt'), function(error, result, response){
  if(!error){
    // blob retrieved
  }
});
```

Has anyone else used node.js/express to download files from Azure blob storage? Did you use Azure, or another method (ex. Request). Could you share how to get a file from Azure and stream it to a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a full tutorial on using Azure Storage Blobs with Node.js [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage/). The tutorial mentions getBlobToLocalFile which sounds like what you're probably looking for. The syntax for this method should be extremely similar to getBlobToStream but instead of a stream you'll provide a file path.

Answer (score 1):

I was creating a function that downloads a folder(virtual) of blobs and returns a zip file. The easiest implementation was to download them as files with **getBlobToLocalFile**, export as a .zip and finally delete the temp file.
**This might not be the best solution, but it's easier to implement.**
I know it's not the most efficient way, but it's good enough for me.

Step 1, get list of blobs:

```
 blobService.listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix(
  containerName,
  prefix,
  null,
  { delimiter: "", maxResults: 100 },
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve(result.entries);
    }
  }
);
```

Step 2, save locally:

```
 blobs.map(blob => {
  blobService.getBlobToLocalFile(
    containerName,
    blob.name,
    `${baseDir}/${blob.name}`,
    (err, blob) => {
      if (err) {
        //handle error
      } else {
        count++;
        //do something after they all save
    }
  );
});
```